# natural_number(1) -> false. Problems with s/1 predicate

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I'm using swi-prolog. I'm simply trying to follow the examples in the book "the art of prolog", but I'm not getting the correct results. I'm afraid this might be due to the s/1 predicate. I can't even find s/1 in the documentation for swipl, the only predicate that is similar is succ/2: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=succ/2 This can't be used the same way as s/1. I'd much prefer to have the s predicate.

This is the program for determining whether a number is a natural number:

```
natural_number(0).
natural_number(s(X)) :- natural_number(X).
```

However, natural_number(1) for example yields false. What's the problem here?

Comment: `natural_number(1)` is false because, according to your definition, `1` is not a natural number. The natural numbers, per your rules, are `0`, `s(0)`, `s(s(0))`, ... *etc*. `s/1` isn't a predefined predicate. It's just a term that means *successor of...*. I think you need to explain what you're really trying to achieve here. You said, *This can't be used the same way as s/1. I'd much prefer to have the s predicate.* Can you elaborate on this and explain what you want?

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks. I thought swi prolog had an internal mechanism to convert actual integers to corresponding s(..) expressions and vice versa.

Comment: No, it's an example that shows how unification works!
change the second line to `natural_number(X) :- succ(N,X), natural_number(N)` to let it work with your example tho :)
Good luck learning!

Comment: You can only convert ground s(X) terms into a number e.g. s(s(0)) = 2 but which number would you assign to s(s(X))?